Normal distribution and conditional expectation
Why is $E(X|X>a) \left( 1- \Phi\left( \frac{ln(a)-\mu}{\sigma} \right) \right)=E(X) \left( 1-\Phi\left( \frac{ln(a)-\mu}{\sigma} -\sigma \right)\right)$?
Maybe it's easy but I do not see it.


Where's the snapshot from? I don't think it's correct.

It is from page 10 (solution of task from page 9) of
https://aktuar.de/aktuar-werden/pruefungsorganisation/Loesungsvorschlaege_klausuren/musterloesungen/004SMusterloesung2009neu.pdf
The language is german.

Okay, it turns out it’s just a simple integral calculation, you don’t even need to rewrite it as a conditional expectation. Consider the following function:
$$
q(a)=\int_{a}^{\infty}x f(x)dx
$$
where $f(x)$ is the lognormal distribution. When plugging it into the integral, you get:
$$
q(a)=\int _{a}^{\infty}{\frac {1}{\sigma {\sqrt {2\pi }}}}\exp \left(-{\frac {(\ln x-\mu )^{2}}{2\sigma ^{2}}}\right)dx
$$
Now, consider a change of variables:
$$
\Bigg|
\begin{array}{l}
y&={\frac {\ln x-\mu }{\sigma }} \\
dx&=\sigma \exp\left(\sigma y+\mu \right)dy
\end{array}
\Bigg|
$$
yielding
$$
\int _{y=(\ln a-\mu )/\sigma }^{\infty }{\frac {1}{\sigma {\sqrt {2\pi }}}}
\exp\left(-{\frac {1}{2}}y^{2}\right)\sigma \exp\left(\sigma y+\mu \right)dy
$$
combine the exponentials together and complete the square:
$$
\int {\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi }}}\exp\left[-{\frac {1}{2}}(y-\sigma )^{2}+(\mu +{\frac {1}{2}}\sigma ^{2})\right]dy
$$
Take out factors independent of integration from the integral
$$
q(a)=\exp\left(\mu +{\frac {\sigma ^{2}}{2}}\right){\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi }}}\int _{y=(\ln a-\mu )/\sigma }^{\infty }\exp\left(-{\frac {1}{2}}(y-\sigma )^{2}\right)dy
$$
Use yet another variable change
$$
\Bigg|
\begin{array}{l}
u&=y-\sigma \\
du&=dy
\end{array}
\Bigg|
$$
to obtain
$$
q(a)=\exp\left(\mu +{\frac {\sigma ^{2}}{2}}\right){\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi }}}\int _{u=(\ln a-\mu )/\sigma -\sigma }^{\infty }\exp\left(-{\frac {1}{2}}u^{2}\right)du
$$
The first factor turns out to be (by definition) the expectation of a lognormal variable with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$. The rest is a survival function of a standard normal variable.
$$
q(a)=\mathbb{E}_{X\sim LN(\mu, \sigma)}[x]\left(1-\Phi \left({\frac {\ln a-\mu -\sigma^{2}}{\sigma }}\right)\right)
$$

Thanks. Now I see it!
